# GraphQL resolve GraphQLObjectType

Tags: javascript, express, graphql

I'm using [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql) along with the following query:

```
invitations {
    sent 
    received
}
```

The schema definition (simplified) is as follows:

```
const InvitationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'InvitationType',
    description: 'Friends invitations',
    fields: {
        sent: {
            type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString),
            description: 'Invitations sent to friends.',
            resolve() {
             return ['sentA'];
            }
        },
        received: {
            type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString),
            description: 'Invitations received from friends.',
            resolve() {
             return ['receivedA', 'receivedB'];
            }
        }
    }
});

// Root schema
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: 'RootQueryType',
      fields: {
          invitations: {
              type: InvitationType // no resolve() method here.
          }
      }
    })
});
```

However the `resolve` methods are never called for `sent` and `received` fields. The query above returns:

```
{data: {invitations: {sent: null, received: null}}}
```

Is there any way to resolve the nested fields (`sent` and `received`) without defining a `resolve()` method on parent (`invitations`) field?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me! According to [GraphQL Documentation](http://graphql.org/learn/execution/), The execution will continue if the resolve method returns a non-scalar. So the following code works:

```
// Root schema
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: 'RootQueryType',
      fields: {
        invitations: {
          type: InvitationType,
          resolve: () => ({}) // Resolve returns an object.
        }
      }
    })
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!